# Where is boost's managed_external_buffer defined?

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess

In boost/interprocess/managed_external_buffer.hpp, a template class basic_managed_external_buffer is defined, yet I can't manage to find the actual definition of the managed_external_buffer class (which I guess simply inherits from the previous one with particular template parameters).

I'm also looking for the definition of the managed_shared_memory class, I also find a basic_managed_shared_memory template class in the managed_shared_memory.hpp file, but no definition of the actual managed_shared_memory class.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try grep, Agent Ransack, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `boost/interprocess/interprocess_fwd.hpp`:

```
typedef basic_managed_external_buffer
   <char
   ,rbtree_best_fit<null_mutex_family>
   ,iset_index>
managed_external_buffer;
```

The other one is right there, too.

Answer (score 1):

From `<boost/interprocess/interprocess_fwd.hpp>`:

```
template <class CharType
         ,class MemoryAlgorithm
         ,template<class IndexConfig> class IndexType>
class basic_managed_external_buffer;

typedef basic_managed_external_buffer
   <char
   ,rbtree_best_fit<null_mutex_family>
   ,iset_index>
managed_external_buffer;
```